# Complex query neo4j from GraphObject

Tags: neo4j, cypher, procedure, py2neo

I am using GraphObject to map Neo4j nodes to Python Classes, I like when I get a Node with relationships because I get its nodes too as Python Classes. For example, if my class is Person, I can use Person.select, and get Person objects.

Now, I need to execute a complex query so that It needs to call a spatial procedure, I can only do this with graph.run("MY_COMPLEX_QUERY"), but this returns nodes (and these nodes don't have relationships).

Is it posible to execute any query with GraphObject selector with a single query? Any ideas?

Thanks!!,
Regards

PD: I can get all ids, and after use Person.select by id, but it isn't good solution.

Comment: If you can construct your query in terms of a predicate expression (`WHERE <condition>`) then you can use `Person.select(*args).where("<predicate expression>")` to append predicates to that specialized select query. But you really shouldn't rely on the `py2neo` OGM to do any level of complex work, it utilizes only a very small subset of Cypher.

Comment: Hi, I can't, I need to call spatial procedure. Thanks
I think to create a static method that it transforms node Neo4j to Json, and so I only use one query (but I need to keep two similar methods by class...).
Any more solution? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it all in one query. Behind the scenes, `py2neo` doesn't even appear to do all of its work in one query. If you really want to get GraphObjects, you can do it from a list of nodes like so:

```
def make_GraphObjects(graph, GraphObjectCls, nodes):
    for node in nodes:
        obj = GraphObjectCls.wrap(node)
        graph.pull(obj)
        yield obj
```

That will be more than one transaction, but that's the limit of using the OGM. It claims to simplify your interactions, but I find it mostly just limits them.